# How to display sum total for currently selected series in NVD3.js Pie Chart?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, charts, nvd3.js

I would like to show sum total of the currently selected series in NVD3.js Pie Chart.

Consider the following data:

```
[
  { "label": "One",   "value": 100 }, 
  { "label": "Two",   "value": 200 }, 
  { "label": "Three", "value": 300 }
]
```

I would like to display a total value of 600 in the middle of a pie chart when all series are selected. But when, for example, I deselect series "One", I would like the total value to be updated to 500.

I can display initial total value using `title` attribute in my react.js component:

```
const getTotal = () => {
  return d3.sum(data, (d) => d.value );
};

return (
  <div>
    <NVD3Chart
      title={getTotal()}
      type="pieChart"
      datum={data}
      x="label"
      y="value"
      donut
      donutRatio="0.4"
    />
  </div>
);
```

However, I couldn't find a way to dynamically update the total value when user selects or deselects data series for the chart's series.

Is there a way to dynamically update the title to match the sum total of the selected series in the chart?

Link to my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ghmpo42k/210/

Comment: Can you post a plunkr/js fiddle? You'd want to hook into the onChange handler.

Comment: @jeznag Link to my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ghmpo42k/210/

Answer (score 0):

React isnt aware of your modification inside nvd3.js, so there is re-rendering. I dont know if there is any method "updateTitle" for nvd3.js (it would be the best use). 
If there is a change in your render without using setState (like changing a node under your state without changing its reference), you can call this.forceUpate(), it will force re-render your component.

Note that this should, as much as possible, be avoided.